# NullPointerException while changing textView text in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, dialog, textview, customdialog

**Background:**

- I just want to create a customDialog with a specific layout and add the content.
- Its a DialogFragment

**Code:**

```
TextView text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 text = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lorem);
 text.setText("Test");
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
 builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null));
 return builder.create();
}
```

**Problem:**

- The Dialog worked, but after I started to add the the lines in "onCreate" I got a NullPointerException Error. I hope someone can help me.

---

Thanks @Raghunandan for the Answer + explanation and here is the working code:

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_style, null);
     textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
     textView.setText("Test");
     builder.setView(view);
     return builder.create();
    }
```

Comment: useSetContentView instead of setView

Comment: @QadirHussain its a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @vyn use the view object to initialize your views. remve the code in `onCreate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first i thought its a `Activity` now i see its a `DialogFragment`.

I am guessing the view belongs to `custom_dialog.xml`

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lorem); 
builder.setView(view);
```

So use the view object to initialize `TextView`.

`text = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lorem);` here `getView()` returns null.

You are calling `setText` on null leading to `NullPointerException`.